# How to show word cloud on map popup using leaflet in r

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, word-cloud, r-leaflet

I am trying to plot the word cloud of sub-categories of that state in popup window when user clicks on that state in map.

```
ui <- bootstrapPage(

   leafletOutput("mymap", height = 300)

)

server <- function(input, output, session){
output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(Sales) %>%
          addTiles() %>%
          addCircles(lng = ~longitude, lat = ~latitude,
                     popup= popupGraph(p),
                     weight = 3,
                     radius = ~Sales,
                     color=~cof(newdata$Category), stroke = TRUE, fillOpacity = 0.8)) )
  
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is my leaflet code, I have used it in r shiny. Can anyone please suggest how i render wordcloud on popup when user clicks on a state on map? I don't know how write that function 'p' for word-cloud in popupGraph(p) but i want to pass it as an argument like this, where p is word-cloud

Comment: Can you make this post reproducible by providing `ui` and `server` code required for the question along with necessary data?

Comment: @RonakShah, i have edited the code. hope it helps

Comment: But still the question is not reproducible as we don't have `Sales` nor `newdata` for `newdata$Category`